# Becoming More OO Multiple For Loops JS

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I have been wanting to become more OO. I develop a little in NetSuite and their APIs are in JS. I have the code below.  Here is what is does.

1) search APIs does search on all transactions that are on the water.

2) Loops through all of the transactions and then searches for everyone of these transactions it does another search on them.  The reason is because NetSuite's API governance only allows a 1000 lines with search APIs (this can be worked around other ways as well). Also want to do it this way because will be working in other logic that will make this way necessary.

3) Then pushes these values, item, quantity, created from record into three arrays. 
4) The last loop loops through the three arrays, but then prints out the item and the created from transaction the number of times of the quantity value.  This is because we are going to print these as labels for each item.

Now have been wanting to become more OO. I did another thing similar where I looped through object with keys and values.  Thought that was neat.  My question is how would you make this more OO. I have some ideas on what I would do but would like to hear some ideas.

1) Create some functions that will call step 3 and step 4.  So each time it looped it called functions
2) I would like to do something with callbacks or promises. Might not be the use for them in this scenario, but 
3) Push the items into an object then run forEach method on those objects.

So the question is how to make this more OO style with JavaScript.

```js
// search APIs
filters = [];
filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('location', null, 'anyof', ['23','25','20','24']);
filters[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'true');

var columns = [];
columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('tranid');
columns[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('createdfrom');

var searchResults =[];
var searchResults = nlapiSearchRecord('itemreceipt', null, filters, columns);

tranId = [];
createdFrom = [];
quantity = [];
item = [];
data = '';

if(searchResults){
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            // gets all internal IDs  
            var tranId = searchResults[i].getValue(columns[0]);

            filtersLine = [];
            filtersLine[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('tranid', null, 'is', tranId);
            filtersLine[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'false');

            var columnsLine = [];
            columnsLine[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('item');
            columnsLine[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('createdfrom');
            columnsLine[2] = new nlobjSearchColumn('quantity');

            var searchResultsLine =[];
            var searchResultsLine = nlapiSearchRecord('itemreceipt', null, filtersLine, columnsLine);


            for (var j = 0; j < searchResultsLine.length; j++){
                  item.push(searchResultsLine[j].getText(columnsLine[0]));
                  createdFrom.push(searchResultsLine[j].getText(columnsLine[1]));
                  quantity.push(searchResultsLine[j].getValue(columnsLine[2])); 

                  for (var x = 0; x < quantity[j]; x++){
                        if(createdFrom[j] != 'undefined'){
                              data += item[j] + createdFrom[j] + '\n'; 
                              console.log(item[j] + ' ' + createdFrom[j].substring(16) + '\n');
                        }
                  }
         
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear and too broad to answer. Please reduce the scope of your problem to something that's easily understandable and answerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running a search per each search result, that's gonna take a hit on your governance points. I checked the code and I see no real need to use that many searches. I have refactored the code to use more functions, also I nested the functions, this should make it more readable and scalable. I also added a couple of filters to avoid getting more data than what you need. Anyways, here's the code, you are welcome to optimize it further.

```
var itemsToProcess = getItemsToProcess();
var data = getDataString(itemsToProcess);

//**** HELPER FUNCTIONS ****//
function getItemsToProcess(){
    // search APIs
    var filters = [];
    filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('location', null, 'anyof', ['23','25','20','24']));
    filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('createdfrom', null, 'isnotempty'));
    filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('quantity', null, 'greaterthan', 0)); //Filtering out items with no quantity
    filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'F')); //Dont want to get any extra info
    filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('shipping', null, 'is', 'F')); //Dont want to get any extra info
    filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('cogs', null, 'is', 'F')); //Dont want to get any extra info
    filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('taxline', null, 'is', 'F')); //Dont want to get any extra info

    var columns = [];
    columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('item'));
    columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('createdfrom'));
    columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('quantity'));

    var searchResults = fullSearch('itemreceipt', filters, columns);

    var rows = [];
    for(var i in searchResults){
        var result = {};
        result.item = searchResults[i].getText(columnsLine[0]);
        result.createdFrom = searchResults[i].getText(columnsLine[1]);
        result.quantity = searchResults[i].getValue(columnsLine[2]);
        rows.push(result);
    }
    return rows;

    //**** HELPER FUNCTIONS ****//
    function fullSearch(type, filters, columns){
        var search = nlapiCreateSearch(type, filters, columns);
        var resultset = search.runSearch();
        var resultsets = [];
        var returnSearchResults = [];
        var searchid = 0;
        var startdate, enddate, resultslice;
        /* Grabs results first */
        do {
            resultslice = getResultSlice(resultset, searchid);
            for (var rs in resultslice) {
                returnSearchResults.push(resultslice[rs]);
                searchid++;
            }
        } while (resultslice.length == 1000);

        return returnSearchResults;

        //*********** HELPER FUNCTION ***********/
        function getResultSlice(resultset, searchid){
            var resultslice = resultset.getResults(searchid, searchid + 1000);
            return resultslice || [];
        }
    }

}

function getDataString(itemsToProcess){
    var data = '';
    for(var i in itemsToProcess){
        data += printItem(itemsToProcess[i].item, itemsToProcess[i].createdFrom, itemsToProcess[i].quantity);
    }
    return data;

    //**** HELPER FUNCTIONS ****//
    function printItem(item, createdFrom, quantity){
        var tempString = '';
        for (var x = 0; x < quantity; x++){
            console.log(item + ' ' + createdFrom.substring(16));
            tempString += item + createdFrom + '\n'; 
        }
        return tempString;
    }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU for converting that index access to Array.push() calls. Drives me nuts how poor the code samples in the NetSuite help are, then you see it show up in questions and it's such a shame.